# Is there any user flow that allow changing the login email?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

As the title says, is there any way to create a user flow that allows changing the login email login?

Comment: Are your users stored within the B2C Azure Active Directory, or elsewhere? Are you looking for a flow or policy that will enable an authenticated user to change their email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do this with a user flow.

You have to use [custom policies](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/change-sign-in-name).

Yes:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
```

requires the user to validate the email. The "Verified.Email" is the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a user flow that allows changing the login email by using custom policies.
For example by adding the OutputClaim

`<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" />`

to the SelfAsserted-ProfileUpdate technical profile.
This will also require the user to verify the new email address.

Comment: Does the PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" triggers verify email UI?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It triggers the verification.